# Unable to use mpdf with laravel 5

Tags: php, mpdf

I am working on my laravel 5 app and I am stuck here. In Code Igniter, I had this code which I use to generate pdf and it was working well:

```
$mypdf = new mPDF();
$mypdf->WriteHTML($css, 1);
$mypdf->WriteHTML($html_data, 2);
$mypdf->Output();
```

On laravel is not working, instead the browser keeps searching for ever. When I exit the server with `CRTL + C`, and restart with `php artisan serve`, I get the message below:

```
[Fri Nov 20 15:37:16 2015] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
```

Each time, I would to use `sudo netstat -plnt` and `kill` command to terminate the php process before the server can be started again.

The code in laravel is like below:

```
 $content = view('letters.internship_offer_letter_en_pdf', compact('intern', 'signatory', 'company_logo'))->render();
 $admission_letter_css = public_path().'/css/letter/letter.css';
 $mypdf = new mPDF();
 $mypdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($admission_letter_css), 1);
 $mypdf->WriteHTML($content, 2);
 $mypdf->Output();
```

I have also checked my css, html etc and everything is fine. Infact this exact script works in CodeIgniter which is on apache. It's because I am using the development server for laravel?

What could be wrong? Why is it not working in laravel?

Comment: I am on linux @Ivanka

Comment: Can you do the same, but instead of using `Ctrl + C`, use `Ctrl + /` and see if that kills the process? 
* `CTRL + /` mercilessly kill the process that is currently in the foreground*

Comment: My problem @Ivanka is why is the pdf not generating. I can successfully kill the php process and restart the server. Why is mpdf not working and why is it making the server to behave as such?

Comment: well, is `mpdf` working with other content /views, sample pages/ or this misbehavior is for all files?

Comment: You've come up with a brilliant point @Ivanka. For a fairly simple code as such ```$mypdf = new mPDF();
        $mypdf->WriteHTML('<p>This must work</p>');
        return $mypdf->Output();```, it works

Comment: So the problem is not in Laravel/your server/mpdf, happy debugging! :)

Comment: This same script on CodeIgniter is working fine @Ivanka. Why do I get such a problem in laravel now.

Comment: I would suggest to start with printing your view: `dd(view('letters.internship_offer_letter_en_pdf', compact('intern', 'signatory', 'company_logo'))->render());`

Comment: I have used the command @Ivanka. The html is neat and just as I want. What can really be the issue.

Comment: I have same problem on my localhost (macOS). Have you solved the problem yet?